# How to integrate $a^{\ln{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the step-by-step solution for the following integral:

$$\int{a^{\ln{x}}\,dx}$$

What I've got so far:

Using the identity

$$a^{x} = e^{\ln{a^{x}}} = e^{x\ln{x}}$$

$$a^{\ln{x}} = e^{\ln{a^{\ln{x}}}} = e^{\ln{x}\ln{a}}$$

Therefore:

$$\int{a^{\ln{x}}} = \int{e^{\ln{x}\ln{a}}}$$

My intuition tells me the answer is something like:

$$\left[\frac{e^{\ln{x}\ln{a}}}{\frac{\ln{a}}{x}}\right] + C$$

But it isn't. Any pointers?

Comment: $$a^{\ln x}=e^{\ln a \ln x}=x^{\ln a},$$ so it depends on the value of $a$ a bit what you need to do next. ($a=1/e$ is a special case)

Comment: Hint: $\exp(\ln x\ln a)=x^{\ln a}$.

Comment: A similarly ‘difficult’ integral would be $\displaystyle\int e^{x^{^{\displaystyle\frac{\ln(ax+b)}{\ln x}}}}dx\quad=\quad?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a^{\ln{x}}=e^{\ln{x} \ln{a}} = x^{\ln{a}}$$

Therefore

$$\int dx \, a^{\ln{x}} = \int dx \, x^{\ln{a}} = \frac{1}{1+\ln{a}} x^{\ln{a}+1}+C$$

Comment: ... provided $a \ne \frac{1}{e}$ :)

Comment: @mike4ty4: correct.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $e^{(\ln x)\ln a }= \left(e^{\ln x}\right)^{\ln a} = x^{\ln a}$.  Since $\ln a$ is a constant, then $\displaystyle\int x^{\ln a} \,dx = \ldots$

Answer (score 1):

$$
a^{\ln x}=e^{\ln x\ln a}=e^{\ln x^{\ln a}}=x^{\ln a}.
$$